Remove Apple Development Certificates
I got a MacBook used by an other employee of my company.
On XCode when I go to Settings > Account > Selected item in Team > Manage Certificates I have 2 certificates in the category Apple Development Certificates where the creator mail is mine:

MacBook Pro of XXX
company's iMac Pro

Both are disabled with status Not in Keychain
I can't create a new Development certificate because I got the error:

You alreay have a current Development certificate or a pending
certificate request.

How can I remove those 2 certificates ? I didn't see anything on developer.apple.com
Thanks
